# execute Python script from bash with argument

Tags: python, bash

I am learning python so came across below situation and looking some suggestion,

I have a python fine '**clone_run.py**' and I am able to execute this file with argument from **terminal** as mentioned below and it works fine.

```
python3.7 ./clone_run.py 900022 0017 700000 0001 --create
```

Now I would like to put this code in bash script which does not work. I tried various options. One of them is mentioned below.

In bash file (bash_example.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh    
python /path/to/file/clone_run/clone_run.py "900022 0017 700000 0001 --create"
```

On execution of bash_example.sh it displays below syntex error

```
  File "./bash_example.sh", line 7
    python /path/to/file/clone_run/clone_run.py "900022 0017 700000 0001 --create"
                                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're trying to run the bash file as a python file. The error is a python error. Show how you ran `bash_example.sh` please. I bet it was with `python bash_example.sh`

Comment: Do you want to pass one argument to your python script or several? The first example shows multiple arguments, but the second one shows one argument inside quotes. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks guys I tried again without the "". and works fine. i.e.  python /path/to/file/clone_run/clone_run.py 900022 0017 700000 0001 --create

Answer (score 1):

if your question is **how to give argument in a python program from the bash** then you can do this,

```
python3 pyfile.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

in the code you can access the arguments by,

```
import sys
argument1 = sys.argv[1] #argument1 = arg1
argument2 = sys.argv[2] #argument2 = arg2
argument3 = sys.argv[3] #argument3 = arg3
```

sys.argv[0] = program name(pyfile.py), so we started from argv[1].